# Location of JNDI file

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

Since I am new to EJB, I do not know where to search for the JNDI file of an EJB 3.0 project. I am told that in order to access the EJB classes, we need to lookup the class using the JNDI. So can anyone please suggest where do I usually find the JNDI file for an EJB project?

**Note :** Since EJB 3.0 is used, the concept of ejb-jar.xml is not used. So please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no JNDI file.but the JNDI names can be found for the EJBs in weblogic server for EJB 2.0. on the other hand, for EJB 3.0, the JNDIs can be found in web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

there are is no JNDI files, it allow to find objects via the name

Comment: Are you saying that JNDI is something that allows the user to find object via their name?

Comment: I have an EJB - `BusinessSLSB` that is created using annotations. In that case, how do I lookup this EJB class? There is no ejb-jar xml involved as it is using EJB 3.0.